# How to implement Pagination in JSP Without DisplayTag Library

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to implement pagination in my jsp and so far what I have found so far is `DisplayTag` library. It is fine but if I go this route I would have to change the current implementation of my jsp which I don't want. Meaning `DisplayTag` has its own tags. So, is there any other way to achieve pagination in JSP. I am really new to Pagination so probably need some info as well.

JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${intgList}" var="list">
        <tr class="<%=count % 2 != 0 ? "odd" : "even"  %>">
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.lob}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.insuredName}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.custPhone}" /></td>
            <c:if test="${list.policyNbrLink eq true}">
                <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><a href='#x' style="text-decoration:none" onclick="locateFunc('viewESignPolicyDetails',
                                                                                                                    {'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                                                                                                                     'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                                                                                                                     'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                                                                                                                     'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                                                                                                                     'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                                                                                                                     'transId':'${list.transId}',
                                                                                                                     'lob':'${list.lob}',
                                                                                                                     'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                                                                                                                     'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                                                                                                                     'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                                                                                                                     'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'}
                                                                                                                    )"><c:out value="${list.policyNumber}"/></a></td>
            </c:if>  
            <c:if test="${list.policyNbrLink eq false}">
                <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.policyNumber}"/></td>
            </c:if>
            <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><c:out value="${list.createdDate}" /></td>
            <td class="dataFieldCellWrap" align="center"><c:out value="${list.custEmail}" /></td>
             <td class="dataFieldCell1" align="center"><a href='#x' onclick="locateFunc('viewESignDetails',
                                                                     {'url':'<integration:urlAction actionName="/integration/viewDetailsIntegration"><integration:urlParam key="esignIdentifier" value="${list.esignId}"/></integration:urlAction>',
                                                                     'agencyCode':'${list.agencyCode}',
                                                                     'policyNumber':'${list.policyNumber}',
                                                                     'policyState':'${list.policyState}',
                                                                     'esignIdentifier':'${list.esignId}',
                                                                     'esignVendorIdentifier':'${list.esignVendorIdentifier}',
                                                                     'lob':'${list.lob}',
                                                                     'transId':'${list.transId}',
                                                                     'customerName':'${list.insuredName}',
                                                                     'customerPhone':'${list.custPhone}',
                                                                     'customerEmail':'${list.custEmail}',
                                                                     'cretedDate':'${list.createdDate}'}
                                                                    )"><c:out value="${list.esignNumDocs}"/></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <%count++;%>
    </c:forEach>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pagination can be as easy as: Just use a regular `for` rather than `foreach` and change the starting index.

Comment: And you are as complicated as your answer. What I asked was that I am new to it and you are marking my question down.

Comment: What's wrong with Display tag library, you can get so many features out of it.

Comment: @developerwjk. he doesn't want to change the jsp code why are you suggesting then?

Comment: I don't get him. I don't want to change the jsp code at all. This is the order guys.

Comment: _"he doesn't want to change the jsp"_, _"So, is there any other way to achieve pagination in JSP."_ -- Without changing the JSP? Of course not. How will you accomplish _anything_ "in JSP" if you can't change the JSP?

Comment: @developerwjk. I don't want to use a library that got its own tags. Display Tag library got its own tags like <table:column> etc. I don't want to use just because of that. Therefore I am asking if anyone has used something to achieve the same thing without introducing new tags.

Comment: See this change is reasonable because there is usage of third party library. This is my first time implementing this in the web project. Have you encountered any example using for loop. I am sure I am not gonna get a paginated page just by using for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but I had to use Display Tag library because it comes with so many other features like export as csv or even as xml. Sorting and pagination etc. Since I am using Display tag I had to change the jsp (table reformatting) to be able to support the diplay tag features.

Comment: Yes you did Syed :)